JS, Is there a way web client access file cached date of image url?
I have a react component for thumbnails in client,
export default function Thumbnail({
  url,
  updatedDate, // updatedDate is from server api
}) {
  const cachedDate = new Date(.....);
  const queryStr = cachedDate < updatedDate ? '?force=' + Math.random() : '';

  return (
    <img
      src={url + queryStr}
      alt={'THUMB'}
    />

)}

How can I get cachedDate? Is it possible?
